# mocha js with react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to write test scripts using mocha js for my react code. The test helper file is like this
browser.js

```
var baseDOM = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body></body></html>';
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
global.document = jsdom(baseDOM);
global.window   = document.defaultView;
if ( global.self != null) {
  console.log(' global.self >>>>> ' + global.self);
} else {
  global.self = global.this;
}
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

The test script is like this (component.specs.js)

```
'use strict';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { mount, shallow, render } from 'enzyme';
import { App } from '../../js/app.js';
import sinon from 'sinon';
var dispatch = function() {
`enter code here`   console.log('>>>>>>>> Mocking dispatch ');
};

describe('App', function () {
it('App calls check', () => {
     sinon.spy(App.prototype, 'check');
     const enzymeWrapper = mount(<App {...props} />);
     expect(App.prototype.check.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
   });
```

So, when I run npm test, I get the error as 'jsdom is not a function'. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Posible repeat question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194264/mocha-react-navigator-is-not-defined/41195438?noredirect=1#comment75358173_41195438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) but based on the examples I don't think you're using it correctly. jsdom's example code:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
```

What this means for you is that `var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;` should be `var jsdom = require('jsdom').JSDOM;`. The example also uses `new`.

That said, you may want to check out [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) for testing node/react - it's very easy to setup and works well.